# Convertir array double a arreglo string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Necesito convertir un array  double[] unidimensional a un arreglo string[] unidimensional.
este es el codigo como lo intente, utilizo C# en Visual studio 2019.`

```
double[] suma_total_ppa;
suma_total_ppa = new double[cantidad_de_codigos];

double[,] matriz_ppa = new double[info_pieza.GetLength(0), cantidad_de_codigos];

for (int f = 0; f < cantidad_de_codigos; f++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < can; h++)
        {                                         
           suma_total_ppa[f] += matriz_ppa[h, f];                     
        }
    }

    string[] envio = suma_total_ppa.ToString();`
    //error:No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'string[]'
```

Comment: Que tipo es `suma_total_ppa` y `matriz_ppa`? porque mencionas algo unidimensional pero alli veo una matriz, la cual tiene mas de una dimension

Comment: Gracias, por su atención, si ya agregue las declaraciones al código, suma_total_ppa es un arreglo double y matriz_ppa una matriz double., espero haber explicado bien.

Comment: tambien puedes usar un foreach, pero yo me quedo con la solucion de linq, es de mas compleja comprension pero mas eficiente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta claro que un `ToString()` retorna un `string` y no un `string[]`, si quieres un array podrias usar

```
string[] envio = suma_total_ppa.Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Ese es el `Select()` de `linq` que permite iterar y transformar al mismo tiempo

Una forma equivalente de hacerlo sin el `Select()` seria con el `foreach`

```
List<string> temp= new List<string>();

foreach(var item in suma_total_ppa){
    temp.Add(item.ToString());
}

string[] envio = temp.ToArray();
```

pero como veras el codigo queda mas simple con el `Select()`, son muchas menos linea de codigo

Comment: Gracias, que representa `x`. Lo escribi de la forma: `string[] envio = suma_total_ppa.Select(suma_total_ppa.ToString()).ToArray();` pero marca error de sintacsis.

Comment: Tienes que definir un `lambda`, para eso es es el `=>`, la x representa cada item del array que itera https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la referencia, he ampliado mi conocimiento, funciono como decias; `string[] envio = suma_total_ppa.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();`. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una de las soluciones es:

```
string [] envio = Array.ConvertAll(suma_total_ppa, elemento=>elemento.ToString());
```

Comment: Por favor @Firefly explica un poco el error y como lo soluciona tu respuesta!! Ayudaría bastante :)

Comment: Gracias, que se coloca donde va `elemento`?